# Copy all audio files from a folder recursively, while leaving directory structure intact using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, file-transfer

I am trying to move all `.mp3` and `.wav` files from one folder to another, while leaving the relative path of the files the same.

Imagine a directory structure that looks like this:

```
DirA\
  subfolder_1\
    song.mp3
    subfolder_subfolder\
      dj.wav
  somefile.txt
  kittens.jpg
  subfolder_2\
    txt.png
  bass.wav
```

I want to copy the files from `DirA` into `DirB`, so that `DirB` will look like:

```
DirB\
  subfolder_1\
    song.mp3
    subfolder_subfolder\
      dj.wav
  bass.wav
```

Any folder that does not contain any audio files should not be copied over.

I could write a Python or Node.JS script for this or something like that, but I was hoping there would be an easier solution using just PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the in-built `robocopy.exe` with a wildcard list:

```
robocopy "x:\source_dir" "y:\dest_dir" *.wav *.mp3 /S
```

`/S` will recurse, but *not* make empty folders (failed to match wildcard(s)).

Robocopy is resumable if cancelled and can/will skip previously copied files so the same command can be used to refresh a folder tree. It also will take a UNC path (`//server/path`)

`/MIR` or `/purge` can be used to remove any destination files that are no longer in the source.

`robocopy /?` (or [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)) for a list of commands and options.

Comment: AND.. as an added bonus.. will work from anywhere that can call an exe from windows. :)  This was also my first thought.. *sure* you *could* use powershell to write all of this logic.. but this tools was made for this.

Comment: Sweet, this works perfectly! I completely forgot about robocopy, pretty good tool apparently.